# Removing cells from UITableView in iOS, along with an NSMutableArray - error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults

I am making a test to see if I can store questions and answers, and I am using an UITableView. When I come to delete things from the table view, I use this code:

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];{

    }
    NSMutableArray *userQuestions = [defaults objectForKey:@"questionsArray"];
    NSMutableArray *userAnswers = [defaults objectForKey:@"answersArray"];

    [userQuestions removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [userAnswers removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [defaults setObject:userQuestions forKey:@"questionsArray"];
    [defaults setObject:userAnswers forKey:@"answersArray"];

    [defaults synchronize];

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
    }
}
```

When I delete a cell, the app crashes with this report:
`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray removeObjectAtIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'`

At a first glance, I recognised that the NSMutableArray had been passed immutable by the NSUserDefaults. I tried to see if I could put the array into a placeholder array but I had no luck. Does anyone know how I could delete rows from the UITableView correctly?

**Answered**

Thank you everyone that commented, I now have replaced these lines:

`NSMutableArray *userQuestions = [defaults objectForKey:@"questionsArray"];
NSMutableArray *userAnswers = [defaults objectForKey:@"answersArray"];`

with these lines:

`NSMutableArray *userQuestions = [[defaults objectForKey:@"questionsArray"] mutableCopy];
NSMutableArray *userAnswers = [[defaults objectForKey:@"questionsArray"] mutableCopy];`

It works perfectly now that 'userQuestions' and 'userAnswers' are being declared to a mutable copy of an originally immutable array - I understand now. Thanks again!

Comment: I guess you should remove from the data source object then reflect that on your 'NSUserDefaults' object.

Comment: Try - [[defaults objectForKey:@"questionsArray"] mutableCopy];